# Not able to access firebase db in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to firebase and NoSQL.

I'm not able to read the values from **firebase**. Also, I've tried every method but `latlng` returns `null` because it is not added.

Here is the code:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("latlong");
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.i(TAG,postSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            String value = postSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(String.class);
            String value1 = postSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(String.class);
            LatLng n= new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(value),Double.parseDouble(value1));
            latlng.add(n);
```

Comment: Make sure you have to change ```Firebase Database``` rule as ```read:true , write:true```

Comment: yea it is  @GaneshMB

Comment: if you place a breakpoint on `progressDialog.dismiss();` and run the code in a debugger, does it reach that line? If so, if you step through it from there, what line of the code you shared doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: thanks ,it worked the data was  not returning till now ,it returned after some time,some kind of error in db i think so